# Implementing Apple Sign in using django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth, apple-sign-in

I am currently implementing social login using django-allauth.
I've had no problems implementing social logins like Google, Facebook and etc. However, when it came to Apple, the package doesn't seem to work properly.

I've been testing the logins using `https`. Also, I've completed settings in Apple Developer and Django Admin.

The below is the capture of my login page.

[image]

when I click on apple icon, it gets redirected to apple page to proceed.

[image]

When I enter the apple login and complete authentication on apple site, the browser throws `Server Error(500)`.

[image]

I believe my settings for apple sign-in have been correct. The below is my admin settings for apple sign-in.

[image]

I tried to search the references on the internet but I couldn't find anyone experienced the same issue. I have no idea on how to resolve this issue nor do I know the way to find where the error is coming from.

Could anyone suggest any method on how to implement apple sign-in using django-allauth package?

For further information, I've added the below information in the settings.py for apple login details.

```
# apple login settings 

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "apple": {
    "APP": {
        # Your service identifier.
        "client_id" : "example.login",

        # The Key ID (visible in the "View Key Details" page).
        "secret": "1ZBEDD1B.com.example",


        "key": "ABW34RZ6",
        "certificate_key": ""----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY---/46464223aassd/12121f+22+886556656565656545454----END PRIVATE KEY----""}}}
```

Then, I tried to login using apple sign-in in debug. I got this error below.

[image]

Anyone can help on this???

Thanks,

Comment: Can you open debug on settings.py  and share the detailed error with us? You may not need to share with us if you see the exact error :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated the error details on the post which I am facing the first time and enough to make me panic. Would you have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

it took me 5$ and 3 h ... f..k

1. go to [Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list/bundleId) and create new APP ID
   in this APP enable: sign in with Apple, and click

> edit

and check:

> Enable as a primary App ID

(its everything here), save

Your application will appear in the list of created applications, enter it again;
it is important to You to save:
**App ID Prefix** - > it will be your

> "key"

in config file (below)

2. go to [Services](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list/serviceId)
   add new service
   important to You is:
   **Identifier**, it will be your

> client_id

in config below
put ie: pl.your.domain.login.service

enable field: Login with Apple, and click

> Configure

a. select Your app (like in step 1.)

b. give your domain
ie:

> [www.domain.pl](http://www.domain.pl)

c. and add callback url:

> https://www.domain.pl/accounts/apple/login/callback/

**(this url is the one you set in the allauth configuration)**
done, save

3. go to [keys](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list), and generate a new key
   enable here: ** Sign in with Apple** and click `edit`
   select Your APP from step 1.
   download key, be sure, you saved it
   open this file with text Editor copy and paste into

> certificate_key

! open Keys list again and go to edit/preview the created key, you will have **key ID** [on the left, in the middle of the screen], it is needed as

> secret

**(just this ID, without com..domain.etc.)**

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "apple": {
        "APP": {
            
            "client_id": 'YOUR ***SERVICE*** ID -> here from step 2 pl.your.domain.login.service',   
            "secret": 'YOUR KEY ID, IE: ADKKDOOODOOD',
            "key": 'FROM STEP 1: IE DKKDKKKKDK (it is below Your name, right, top corner of main screen in Apple Developer website)',
             "certificate_key": """-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----fileyou have downloaded in step 3 (as plain text)-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"""
        }
    }
}
```

so for me this file looks something like this

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "apple": {
        "APP": {"client_id": 'pl.mydomain.aaaaaa.login.service',
            "secret": 'VXDD556DD5',
            "key": '898SKOLLOS',
"certificate_key": """-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGTAgEAMBdsd0909sd9s0d9s0d90s9d0s9d0sdMGByqG
sdsdsd9s0d90sd9
sddsddsdsd
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
"""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "certification_key" in settings.py file that you're providing doesn't seem to be in the correct format. Make sure that you copy the downloaded key and preserve the line format. Also, make sure to add the certification key in triple quotation marks. I.e.

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "apple": {
        "APP": {
            # Your service identifier.
            "client_id" : "example.login",

            # The Key ID (visible in the "View Key Details" page).
            "secret": "1ZBEDD1B.com.example",

            "key": "ABW34RZ6",

            # The certificate you downloaded when generating the key.
            "certificate_key": """----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--
s3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr
s3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr3ts3cr
c3ts3cr3t
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
"""
        }
    }
}
```

An example is also provided in the django-allauth documentation https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#apple